# error 1054. Unknown coloumn in Insert clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have this problem:
If I write the following query:

```
INSERT INTO prodotto  (Barcode, InseritoDa,  DataInserimento, UrlImage) 
VALUES  ('vfr','ff','12-10-2012', 'vfr.jpg')
```

I get this error message:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'InseritoDa' in 'where clause'
```

But in the table `prodotto` i have this column and its name InseritoDa.

Where am I wrong?
the error may be due to the fact that the field `InseritoDa` is a foreign key that points to another table called `utente`?

the trigger associated to the table is:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `m4af`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `m4af`.`IncrementaProdottiInseritiUtente`
AFTER INSERT ON `m4af`.`prodotto`
FOR EACH ROW
update utente as u
set ProdottiInseriti= (select ProdottiInseriti from utente where username= InseritoDa)+1
where u.username = InseritoDa$$
```

Comment: Do you have triggers defined on that table?

Comment: Have you checked the exact spelling and upper/lowercase for that column? Maybe post a screenshot or the `CREATE TABLE` command of that table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the error states that it occurred in a **WHERE** clause there might be an insert-trigger that executes another query and fails. There is no WHERE clause in your insert statement.

### Edit

Try to edit your INSERT trigger like this:

```
update utente
set ProdottiInseriti = ProdottiInseriti + 1
where username = NEW.InseritoDa
```

Comment: Please show your trigger statement. There is most probably an error in it.

Comment: In your trigger you use a column called `InseritoDa` in table `utente`. Does that table have such a column?

Comment: no, the coloumn InseritoDa is only in the table prodotto but the trigger is called after one insert in to that table so I thought of using it. So, how do I change the trigger?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the trigger? I'm not sure what you want to achive.

Comment: I would like to increase the field prodottiInseriti in the table utente each time it is inserted a product in the table prodotto on the basis of the field inseritoDa.