# Mysql Unknown column on existing column (only insert)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have been researching this problem for quite some time but have not been able to find any helpful results.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
    `jb_id` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `wo_id` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `file_name` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `jb_status` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `descr` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `syncronized` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `failedcnt` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `clip_title` TINYTEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `clip_description` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `clip_tags` TINYTEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    PRIMARY KEY (`jb_id`),
    INDEX `woid` (`wo_id`),
    INDEX `job_stat` (`jb_status`),
    INDEX `synced` (`syncronized`),
    INDEX `failedcnt` (`failedcnt`),
    INDEX `file_name` (`file_name`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_bin'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

When i run SELECT or UPDATE commands everything works ok.

```
select jobs.clip_description from jobs Limit 1;
/* 0 rows affected, 1 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 0.768 sec. */

UPDATE `jobs` SET `clip_description`='test' WHERE  `jb_id`=2 LIMIT 1;
```

But as I try to run

```
INSERT INTO `jobs` (`clip_description`) VALUES ('test');
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'clip_description' in 'field list' */
```

This also happened yesterday, but as i did not have much time to deal with the issue then, i created new table with different name but same structure, copied over all the data and then renamed both tables and it worked again. That is until about two hours ago when the issue returned. It is not really an option to start coping the table every 12h.

For creating a copy i used:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs_new LIKE jobs; INSERT jobs_new SELECT * FROM jobs;
```

After which previously mentioned insert would work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
If it makes any difference I'm running
Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log (Ubuntu)
On ubuntu server 12.04 LTS 64bit

Comment: What happens when you run

INSERT INTO jobs SET clip_description = 'test'?

Comment: INSERT INTO jobs SET clip_description = 'test';
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'clip_description' in 'field list' */

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862081/error-1054-unknown-coloumn-in-insert-clause?rq=1

Comment: Are you able to execute the insert query as default value for not null columns is not set?

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd Thank you so much for pointing me in that direction. I found a before insert trigger that was not working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have other constrains related to table, may be a trigger or some calculated column depending upon clip_description column. Is not it?

Please check the dependencies and triggers with this table.

Comment: Yes, added a comment to previous post i found a coworkers trigger that was using this exact column. SET NEW.clip_description = REPLACE(clip_description,'Old','New'); But had to be SET NEW.clip_description = REPLACE(NEW.clip_description,'Old','New');